Monaco editor - possible to check redo stack?
I do not have any code to share at this point, because I have not been able to find anything on SO or in documentation that specifically addresses this.
I have some custom buttons in my app that perform undo/redo operations.  These work great.
However, what I am looking to do is to disable the "redo" button if there isnt anything to redo.  Is there a way to query the redo stack to see if there is anything in there?

Yes, you can. Short answer is: editor.getModel().canUndo();
See undoRedoService. It has canUndo and canRedo methods: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/cba3b821977fbd1d45eacf0add96cbf9e3865c1e/src/vs/platform/undoRedo/common/undoRedoService.ts#L697
Unfortunately, these two methods are marked as @internal on the ITextModel interface, so TypeScript users would need to cast to any: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/d64d40ad01d0d3a0230b93231332536ec1884b8a/src/vs/editor/common/model.ts#L1197
